# how to remove the generated list of default labels for issues from a gitlab project?

Tags: gitlab, label

In a gitlab project under issues->labels I have pressed the link to generate labels, naively assuming this would allow me generate a customised set of labels for the project. On the contrary I found myself with a set of default labels that unfortunately don't suit me, so I don't want other users to use this set, hence I want the list to disappear again.
How would I achieve that?

Many thanks.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186140/changing-the-default-issue-labels). In 2020, you can add site-wide labels in [the admin area](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/labels.html), and those become the defaults for _new_ projects only. As of this writing, the "Generate a default set of labels" button will still use the ones hard-coded in [`lib/gitlab/issues_labels.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/lib/gitlab/issues_labels.rb) on existing projects, _even if_ you've added site-wide labels in the admin area.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a self-installation as recommended by Gitlab:

```
$ ssh your.gitlab
$ sudo su -l git
$ cd gitlab
$ bundle exec rails console production
> p = Project.where(path: 'your_project').first  # ensure this is your project
> p.issues_default_label_list                    # examine the default list
> p.issues_default_label_list = []               # removes all defaults
> p.save
```

Answer (score 0):

The generation is done by [`app/controllers/projects/labels_controller.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/49a5159946bc8added6258f62efcf7674e4b0562/app/controllers/projects/labels_controller.rb#L10), which uses:

```
@labels = @project.issues_labels
```

This is defined in [`app/models/project.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/49a5159946bc8added6258f62efcf7674e4b0562/app/models/project.rb#L278)

```
def issues_labels
    @issues_labels ||= (issues_default_labels + issues.tags_on(:labels)).uniq.sort_by(&:name)
end
```

Those labels are defined in [`lib/gitlab/issues_labels.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/49a5159946bc8added6258f62efcf7674e4b0562/lib/gitlab/issues_labels.rb).

So if everything else fails, you still can change those values in that file.

```
class IssuesLabels
    class << self
      def important_labels
        %w(bug critical confirmed)
      end

      def warning_labels
        %w(documentation support)
      end

      def neutral_labels
        %w(discussion suggestion)
      end

      def positive_labels
        %w(feature enhancement)
      end
```

---

Note that even if that list was applied when creating an issue, removing labels on said created issue is now easier with [GitLab 13.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/10/22/gitlab-13-5-released/#remove-issue-labels-with-a-single-click) (October 2020)

> ### Remove issue labels with a single click
>
> Removing a label from an issue used to require three clicks, fetching a fresh list of labels from the server, and using a search box to find the label you want to remove. This was unintuitive and inefficient, given that GitLab users remove labels from issues approximately 55,000 times per day.
> It may not be [revolutionary](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/values/#boring-solutions), but you can now remove an issue’s label with a single click.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_5/remove_issue_labels.gif -- Remove issue labels with a single click]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/labels.html#assign-and-unassign-labels) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/216881).

---

With [GitLab 14.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/01/22/gitlab-14-7-released/#delete-labels-directly-from-the-edit-label-page) (January 2022):

> ### Delete labels directly from the Edit Label page
>
> In this release, we’ve added the ability to delete labels in the Edit Label page. This is a usability enhancement that finally allows users to delete labels instead of having a long list of labels called “deprecated”. This includes Admin, Project, and Group labels.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/labels.html#label-management) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/345195).